# what is the pointer to pointer equivalent in lua

Tags: pointers, lua, pointer-to-pointer

I know that you can use tables in a similar way to pointers in lua. That being said, what would pointers to pointers look like? Would they look something like `dp = {p = {}}`? if so what would the equivalent to the c code below be in lua?

```
void InsertItem(node **head, node *newp){
    node **dp = head;

    while((*dp) && (*dp)->value > newp->value
    {
        dp = &(*dp)->next;
    }

    newp->next = *dp;
    *dp = newp;
}
```

Comment: The term "double pointer" is potentially confusing, since it refers to the type `double*`. The term "pointer to pointer" is clearer. See the [tag:double-pointer] tag description page.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Is "double double pointer" a correct name for `double **` ?

Comment: To be precise, references to tables can be used in a similar way as pointers to dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: The correct term for that is "`double`, `double`, toil and trouble".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, double pointer may be translated to Lua as nested table.

```
local function InsertItem(head, newitem)
   while head.next and head.next.value > newitem.value do
      head = head.next
   end
   newitem.next = head.next
   head.next = newitem
end

-- Typical Usage:
local head = {}
InsertItem(head, {value = 3.14})
InsertItem(head, {value = 42})
InsertItem(head, {value = 1})

-- Now the data is the following:
-- head  = {next = elem1}
-- elem1 = {next = elem2, value = 42  }
-- elem2 = {next = elem3, value = 3.14}
-- elem3 = {              value = 1   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The big difference between C pointers and Lua tables is that in C, you can take the address of a variable and pass it to a function to modify it. You can't do that in Lua, but the function could always return the modified value.

> Would they look something like `dp = {p = {}}`?

Yes, that's about as close as close as you can get to a pointer to a pointer in Lua.

> if so what would the equivalent to the c code below be in lua?

Linked lists tend to work more smoothly with recursion:

```
local function InsertItem(head, newp)
  if not head or head.value <= newp.value then
    newp.next = head
    return newp
  end
  head.next = InsertItem(head.next, newp)
  return head
end
```

Comment: In the branch `if not head then` you MUST nullify `newp.next` as it may contain garbage from previous use of this element.

Comment: After looking at it again, I realized the `if` and `elseif` branches were really supposed to be doing the same thing. Fixed.